# Rails: Why does this PG transaction not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have used transactions in many apps in the past and they always worked as expected, and now they're not. I think I'm just blanking on something obvious...

Why does the first record get created?

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  Order.create!(order_id: 12)
  raise 'breaking now'
  Order.create!(order_id: 13)
end
```

I'm using `Rails 6` and `Postgres 12`

Edit: literally nothing works now... I'm so confused. This doesn't work either (the first record gets updated)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  order = Order.first
  order.update(order_id: 777)
  raise 'oops'
  Order.create!(order_id: 13)
end
```

This `Order` model is using a different database, but I tried the same thing on a model which uses the primary database and it had the same effect.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  connects_to database: {reading: :orders, writing: :orders}
end
```

**Edit**: I'm also running this from a fresh `rails c`, so there is no nested transaction in my code that I'm not showing in my example.

Comment: You're connecting to a different database so you should be saying `Order.transaction do ... end `.

Comment: Coincidentally I just ran into the same thing when a swath of ARs were moved to a separate DB.

Comment: so what happens if I need to edit 2 models in the transaction (that are in the same database)? I used to be able to mix models with `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(database: :replica) do
  # you can probably execute plain sql transaction command here and then commit in the end instead of below...
  Order.transaction do 
     # ... all statements that need transaction wrapping from replica
  end
end
```

also, `while_preventing_writes` can be handy:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :orders) do
  Order.connection.while_preventing_writes do
    # will raise because we're blocking writes
    Order.create!
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :orders) do
  Order.connection.while_preventing_writes do
    # will not raise as we're not writing
    Order.first
  end
end
```

Statements can originate from different models but within a single block they should belong to the same database.
The reason for that is: "Transactions are not distributed across database connections" - this is outside of the scope of ActiveRecord (see: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)

If you actually need transaction across models that come from different db connections you'll have to use workaround mentioned in the doc:

```
Student.transaction do
  Course.transaction do
    course.enroll(student)
    student.units += course.units
  end
end
```

Some improvements that might allow a simpler api in this regard seem to be on schedule for Rails 6.1. If you want to learn more - see for example this [comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37837#issuecomment-564636993) and the referenced [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37622).

Comment: Awesome, so I assume I still need the Base.transaction inside the connected_to right? Thanks so much for your answer

Comment: Yes. In general as it says in the doc: "Though the transaction class method is called on some Active Record class, the objects within the transaction block need not all be instances of that class. This is because transactions are per-database connection, not per-model." 

So, you can use Order.transaction for multiple models. If that seems weird you can make an abstract model (`MyDbBase < ActiveRecord::Base`) and then inherit A, B,  from it.